# Having an issue using Calabash-Android to resign android apk file

Tags: android, macos, ant, automated-tests, calabash

I am trying to figure out what I'm missing to get calabash-android to sign an apk file. Any help is appreciated. Console log below. Currently running  Mac OS X 10.9

```
Last login: Thu Jan 23 09:25:44 on console
xxxxx2m3:~ xxxxx2$ echo $ANDROID_HOME
/Users/xxxxx2/android/android-sdk/sdk
xxxxx2m3:Calabash_Automation xxxxx2$ calabash-android resign android-app.apk 
/Users/xxxxx2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/calabash-android-0.4.18/lib/calabash-android/helpers.rb:102:in `sign_apk': private method `sign_apk' called for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/xxxxx2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/calabash-android-0.4.18/lib/calabash-android/helpers.rb:82:in `block in resign_apk'
    from /Users/xxxxx2/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tmpdir.rb:88:in `mktmpdir'
    from /Users/xxxxx2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/calabash-android-0.4.18/lib/calabash-android/helpers.rb:76:in `resign_apk'
    from /Users/xxxxx2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/calabash-android-0.4.18/bin/calabash-android:107:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/xxxxx2/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/calabash-android:23:in `load'
    from /Users/xxxxx2/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/calabash-android:23:in `<main>'
    from /Users/xxxxx2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/xxxxx2/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
xxxxx2m3:Calabash_Automation xxxxx2$ android
xxxxx2m3:Calabash_Automation xxxxx2$ calabash-android build android-app.apk 
No keystores found.
Please create one or run calabash-android setup to configure calabash-android to use an existing keystore.
xxxxx2m3:Calabash_Automation xxxxx2$ calabash-android setup
Please enter keystore information to use a custom keystore instead of the default
Please enter keystore location

Please enter the password for the keystore

Please enter the alias

Saved your settings to .calabash_settings. You can edit the settings manually or run this setup script again
xxxxx2m3:Calabash_Automation xxxxx2$
```

Any help would be appreciated. This has been frustrating me for a while.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/wiki/Running-Calabash-Android

There it is explained how to resgin the app.
Use **calabash-android setup** and set the following:
- keystore location: **~/.android/debug.keystore**
- password: **android**
- alias: **androiddebugkey**

Answer (score 0):

I have a file called calabash-settings with the content:

{"keystore_location":"...","keystore_password":"...","keystore_alias":"..."}

inside the folder where I execute calabash